# PageRank sharing between domains?

Tags: seo, domains, pagerank, multiple-domains, nameserver

I own three domains, say.. **example.com, example.in, example.co.in**

I have bought the .in and .co.in TLDs (Top Level Domains) only to protect the brand.

But I have this question:

If I make the other two also point to my hosting so that regardless of which one the user types, they are taken to the same website, will the Page Rank be split into three and will each domain have one third the actual PR value?

What should I do with the other two domains? Where should I point them to, if I don't intend to use them at all (i.e., what should I give in place of the `ns1.myprovider.com`, `ns2.myprovider.com` etc..?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you point them all to the same content, and do not do a 301 redirect to a "main" domain, then you will be splitting up PR amongst domains (assuming you have links to all of them) and also have duplicate content. The duplicate content will result in pages being penalized and/or removed from the index.

Choose a "main" domain that you always want to appear in the user's address bar and then use .htaccess to redirect anyone who uses the secondary domains to forward to the main domain.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondarydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondarydomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Should the `^(www\.)?secondarydomain1\.com$` part be `^(www\.)?example\.in$` and `^(www\.)?example\.co\.in$` in my case? Is my syntax correct?

Comment: That looks correct.